# jQuery Mobile: open dialog with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I'm using jQuery Mobile and I need to open a dialog whit dynamic content.

This is the JS code:

```
$('.link').on( "click", function() {

    html = '';
    html += '   <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="b" class="header">';
    html += '       <h1>Title</h1>';
    html += '   </div>';
    html += '   <div id="dialog-content">text</a>';

    $('#dialog').html(html);
    $.mobile.changePage("#dialog");
});
```

This is the div used as dialog:

```
<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="dialog"></div>
```

The first time it works perfectly. The second time I'm not able to clear the dialog content and put into it the new one. The new content appears in addiction to the first one.
If I try to clear the dialog content it doesn't works:

```
$('#dialog').empty();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The version number of `jQM` you're using would be helpful. Plus the rest of your code or better still, a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing and recreating the whole dialog instead of just the contents:

```
$('.link').on( "click", function() {    
    html = '';
    html += '<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="dialog" >';
    html += '   <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="b" class="header">';
    html += '       <h1>Title</h1>';
    html += '   </div>';
    html += '   <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="dialog-content">text</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    $('#dialog').remove();
    $('body').append(html);
    $('#dialog').enhanceWithin();
    $.mobile.changePage("#dialog");
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lx82g/)**

Also, instead of changePage, in 1.4 you should start using the pagecontainer:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer( "change", "#dialog");
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lx82g/2/)**

Comment: It seems to not be possibile to change the page-transition effect: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx82g/4/

Comment: Easy, $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#dialog", {transition: "flow"}); Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lx82g/5/

Answer (score -1):

I thing that the most correct way to resolve this problem is:

You should not create dialog dynamically.

Just Update the dialog content, is more simple than this work arround: http://cbtechdev.blogspot.com/2015/11/jquery-mobile-dialog-update-content.html

```js
update_dialog_content = function(){
    var dialog = $("#dialog");
    dialog.find('div[data-role=content]').html($('#content').val());
}

$('#show').click(update_dialog_content);
```

```html
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="page" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>jQuery Mobile</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <input id='content' />
            <a id="show" href="#dialog" data-role="button">Show Dialog</a>           
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog" data-role="dialog">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>jQuery Mobile Dialog</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            Place content here
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```